# Como iterar a través de una lista de diccionarios que esta en un archivo .json

Tags: python

Tengo un archivo users.json que tiene una lista con un diccionario por cada usuario:

```
[
{
    "user_id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
    "email": "facundo@example.com",
    "first_name": "Facundo",
    "last_name": "Garcia",
    "birth_date": "2021-10-28",
    "password": "holasoyfacundo"
},
{
    "user_id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
    "email": "miguel@example.com",
    "first_name": "Miguel",
    "last_name": "Torres",
    "birth_date": "2021-10-28",
    "password": "holasoymiguel"
},
{
    "user_id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
    "email": "Rocio@example.com",
    "first_name": "Rocio",
    "last_name": "Torres",
    "birth_date": "2021-10-28",
    "password": "holasoyrocio"
}
```

]

Ahora quiero validar que un correo y una contraseña estén dentro del archivo de usuarios. Lo intente con este código pero me da este error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

```
email = "facundo@example.com"
password = "holasoyfacundo"

with open("users.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for user in f:
        if email == user["email"] and password == user["password"]:
            print('Login Succesfully!')
            break
    else:
        print("Login Unsuccesfully!")
```

Comment: al leer el archivo estas leyendo una cadena de caracteres y no un diccionario, para convertir eso en un diccionario python válido debes usar el módulo `json`

Comment: Básicamente, te hace falta aplicar [esto: Reading JSON from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20199213/13636459), ya que estás leyendo el archivo línea por línea no en el formato JSON. Va a empezar a buscar en el string `[{`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar `json` y pasar directamente el archivo, el se encargará de todo.

```
import json

json_file = open("./your_json_file.json")

data = json.load(json_file)

for user in data:
    print(user['first_name'])
```